# Принадлежность сайтов

Tags: хостинг

Если автор сидит в Украине, а сайт лежит на хостинге, например в США, то тогда этот сайт считается американским и подчиняется американским законам, а не Украинским?

Comment: сайт считается украинским, а вот лежащая на нем инфа доступна только  службам США т.к. сервер располагается на их территории. ну и соответственно органы украины не могут просто так взять и получить данные оттуда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если сайт "лежит" (то есть не работает), а автор "сидит" (то есть получил срок), то какое это имеет значение?:)

А если при этом он в домене .ru, то он русский?

В целом, насколько мне известно, нужно смотреть, где находиться хостинг, который хостит сайт и в договор между хостером и владельцем. Там и прописаны подобные вещи. Но в Вашем случае сайт скорее всего будет подчиняться американским законам.